# How can I get Git to ignore generated and config files?

Tags: git

I have a cache folder that generates php files.
I don't want it to be shown when I type `git status`.

What should I do to ignore this cache folder and the files inside it completely?
I would also like to ignore `config.php` file too.

Comment: Did you do any research about `gitignore` before asking your question?

Comment: yes i did. i tried to add the following code in the file .git/info/exclude/

Comment: cache/datastore/*
cache/feeds/feed_rss_newproducts.xml
config/config.php
product_images/*

Comment: but it did not work.can you please let me know where exactly is the problem

Comment: You need to create a `.gitignore` file in the root folder of your repo and list every files/directories you want to exclude. Provide us the detail of your repository tree and what you want to exclude

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `.gitignore` in the root directory of your git project and add the directories and files you want to exclude:

```
relative/path/to/cache/
relative/path/to/config.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use `.gitignore` and add your unwanted in this file.

1 important thing to remember is that once you have committed file to the repository it will be "tracked" and you will need to tell git not to track changes made to this file from now on. You do it with `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`

Here are few links to learn more about it:

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aj8ifYrzGas
http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/19/ignoring-files.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to track the generated files (as is necessary with `.gitignore`), which seems totally logical to me in this 'it's a cache' scenario then your initial attempt is certainly the way to go. Did the downvoters on this question overlook the words 'generated' (in the title) and 'cache' (in the content) of the OP's question?

I added explicit paths relative to the project root to the file `.git/info/exclude` just as you did (bar the typo on the exclude path) and it worked as expected (msysgit v1.9.5). Thanks for the solution.